# How can I move the camera to create a parallax effect?

Tags: unity, 3d

Right now I am making an application which can be described as model viewer for iPad Pro. The client wants to have an orbiting camera around the object and in addition he wants to have a parallax effect similar to iPhone 3D wallpapers which will is based of of tilt of the tablet.

My problem right now is that I am not really sure how to calculate the parallax effect and how to rotate the camera (or model) to create the 3D effect. Can you give me an idea how to do this ?

Thank you